# xmpp strophe Receive notification subscription when a user logout

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat, strophe

USER A -> send subscribe
USER B -> receive subscribe

I have two users in a chat, when user A sends a subcripcion user B, if this is connected to receive the notification (presence of subscribe), but if the user B is offline when is connected does not receive the notification.

How I can do for the user B receives notification when first connected?

I send the initial presence , but this does not send information subscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For subscriptions, when a users receives the request, an authorization must must sent. See http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#sub. Until the subscription shows "both" in the status, presence notifications won't be sent.

1. USER A > subscribe to USER B
2. USER B > authorize USER A and subscribe to USER A
3. USER A > authorize USER B

Comment: Sorry, but what I need is to notify the user B that user A want add to  roster( when User B is logout), example: 1.- USER A (Login) > Subscribe to USER B , 2.- USER A (Login) > Send Presence type subscribe to USER B, 3.- USER A Logout , 4.- USER B (start Login, connected) > Received Presence USER A, ...etc

Comment: You can't do anything if either one is logged out. Both users must be connected to the jabber server to perform the actions you are looking to do.

Comment: Thanks! I know if its possible.